# Autostart Pi to Website

Tags: boot, chromium

I am trying to get my new Pi to autostart into lets just say google.com whenever its turned on.
I am using the following to try and do this and am having no luck getting to work.

I use terminal to open Nano.
then type in the text below, do a control O to write file and tell it to write as MS DOS.  this doesn't seem to be the right procedure.  I have also tried to exit (ctl x) but it doesn't save any file when I do that.

Any thoughts or insights would be appreciated.

Here is text I am using.

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

@xset s off

@xset -dpms

@xset s nonblank

@chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --incognito --kiosk www.google.com
```

Comment: `write as MS DOS` - but raspbian is Linux, not messy dos? Not saying that's the problem, but I'm not saying it isn't

Comment: The only difference is DOS text files use `/r/n` (carriage return, newline) as a line ending; UNIX text files just use `/n`.  Linux system files are the latter, although the former generally won't matter as the `/r` is just regarded as extraneous whitespace.  However, to rule it out as the source of your problems, don't save stuff that way unless you have a reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create that file using `cat`:

```
sudo cat > ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Then type (or paste) the four lines you want to put there, and terminate with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Be careful, `cat` is not an editor, so you won't be able to modify a line after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.